# Mathematical justification for Le Chatelier's principle

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

At equilibrium

$$
\begin{align}
K &= \exp\left(\cfrac{TΔS^\circ - ΔH^\circ}{RT}\right)\\
⇒ \frac{\mathrm d \ln K}{\mathrm dT} &= \frac{ΔH^\circ}{RT^2}
\end{align}
$$

If enthalpy change is positive, change in $\ln K$ w.r.t. $T$ is positive. Hence, $\ln K$ and therefore $K$ increase (position of equilibrium shifts to the right) as $T$ increases. And, $\ln K$ and therefore $K$ decrease (position of equilibrium shifts to the left) as $T$ decreases.

If enthalpy change is negative, change in $\ln K$ w.r.t. $T$ is negative. Hence, $\ln K$ and therefore $K$ increase (position of equilibrium shifts to the right) as $T$ decreases. And, $\ln K$ and therefore $K$ decrease (position of equilibrium shifts to the left) as $T$ increases.

Can you give a similarly mathematical reasoning for why a reaction

$$\ce{A(g) <=> 2 B(g)}$$

has its equilibrium position shifted to the left as the pressure of the surroundings increases?

Comment: You cannot use that sort of relation to rationalise changes in equilibrium position. The reason is that the van ‘t Hoff relation (the one with d ln K/dT) tells you how the equilibrium constant changes with temperature. When you change the pressure, the equilibrium constant K does *not* change.

Comment: The question is unclear. You have to carefully specify what is in the gas phase (just A and B, or inert gasses as well). $$$$The connection between temperature change and pressure change is that for both, the Gibbs energy of reaction is zero before and after, and equilibrium concentrations/partial pressures change. Of course, @orthocresol is right in saying that in one case, K changes and Q will change to match it again, and in the other case K does not change and Q will return to its starting value (but again, the concentrations change in either case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I might have an answer to my own question:

$$K=exp \left( \frac{TΔS^o-ΔH^o}{RT} \right) $$

implies that *K* is dependent on *T*, but not on total pressure of system, *p* (nor concentrations).

For
$$ A_{(g)}⇌2B_{(g)} $$
$$ K= \frac{{p_{B}}^2}{p_{A}} $$
Partial pressure of a gas = mole fraction (*mf*) x total pressure of system

If *p* is increased then *K* initially increases:
$$ K=\frac{(mf_B.p)^2}{mf_A.p} $$
$$ ⇒ K=\frac{{mf_B}^2.p}{mf_A} $$

But *p* doesn't affect *K*, yet *K* has increased. So the mole fraction of *A* must be increased by shifting the position of equilibrium to the left (thus decreasing the mole fraction of *B*), in order to re-establish the value of *K* to before *p* was increased.